# Angular 2 router-outlet within component template

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template

I have been playing around with routes in Angular 2 but I have run into an issue that I cannot find an answer for. My routes are "working" but not the way I am hoping for. I am trying to use this like you would use ng-view from angular 1, my header and footer never change, and when my url changes new "stuff" is placed in my content.

Here is what I have now which "works"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderComponent } from './shared/header/header.component';
import { ContentComponent } from './shared/content/content.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './shared/footer/footer.component';
import { TestComponent } from './components/test.component';
import { Routes, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';

@Routes([
    {path: '/test', component: TestComponent }
])
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<header></header>
    <a [routerLink]="['/test']">Click for testComponent</a>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <footer></footer>`,
    directives: [HeaderComponent, ContentComponent, FooterComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

What I am trying to do is put the router outlet inside of my `ContentComponent`so that essentially the router just dumps the new stuff directly into the main area of my app. When I try to rewrite:
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
as 
`<content><router-outlet></router-outlet></content>`
 the routing stops working, no error message, just stops. I also do not see my testComponent in the DOM when I inspect it with the devtools. So I thought, well I will put the router-outlet inside the template of my `ContentComponent` like so:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'content',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class ContentComponent { }
```

However when I do this I get the error message: Cannot find default outlet.

I am missing something but the lack of documentation makes it very difficult to figure out, I would think there would be a way to define within @Routes where my outlet is but again, can't find any documentation that isn't for the deprecated-router. Hope someone can shed some light on this. Thanks in advance.

Note: general code critiques would also be helpful, I am very new to Angular 2 and would love the advice.

Comment: Do you also have a Route for ContentComponent? If so, can you please show that as well?

Comment: @MortezaManavi when you say route, do you mean like a path? if so it would be `boilerPlate\app\shared\content\content.component.ts`, If not can you explain what you mean by route?

Comment: No I meant something like this  {path: '/test', component: TestComponent } that you defined for TestComponent. Basically I want to know how the route goes to ContentComponent from AppComponent. It's not in your code as it is here.

Comment: My second question is that why do you need the second router-outlet in ContentComponent's template? Your setup with having one in AppComponent with Header and Footer on above and below it looks good and should get the job done for you.

Comment: @MortezaManavi I am trying to structure it like this `@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `<header></header>
    <a [routerLink]="['/test']">Click for testComponent</a>
    <content></content>
    <footer></footer>`,
    directives: [HeaderComponent, ContentComponent, FooterComponent, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})` This includes <content> I can put demo text in contexts template and I see it where I want it on the screen, so I figured by that logic, including <router-outlet> would display just like my test text would.

Comment: @MortezaManavi as for why I am trying to include a the router in contentComponent, it is because I would like everything I load into that area to have the content styles applied from my css, if this was angular 1 I would basically be placing all of my routed content inside of <div id="content"></div>. Is there a better way to do this? I am trying to go about this the "angular 1" way, and that may be whats causing my problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you call ContentComponent via `<content>` tag makes ContentComponent a child of your AppComponent and you can't place a router-outlet inside a child component's template. One way to achieve what you are after is to create a default route for the ContentComponent in the AppComponent:

```
@Routes([
    { path: '/', component: ContentComponent }
    { path: '/content', component: ContentComponent }
])
```

And AppComponent's template will be:

```
<header></header>     
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<footer></footer>
```

Now you can define nested routes in your ContentComponent like this:

```
@Routes([
    { path: 'content1', component: Content1Component }
])
@Component({
    selector: 'content',
    template: `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class ContentComponent { }
```

And if you have a menu in your header component and want to link to each nested content you can do this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/content', 'content1']">Content1</a>
```

Which will load Content1Component into the ContentComponent's `<router-outlet>`

Comment: I will try this as soon as I get to work tomorrow, I think this is right. It looks familiar but now it makes sense! Thanks! I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Sure, let me know if it doesn't work and we will make it work :)

Comment: It works!, this is what I was trying to do. I do have one questions though. Is this the "right"/intended way to approach routing in Angular 2, or am I hacking it to make it function like angular 1?

Comment: No, I don't think it's a hack or anything like that, that's how I do it in my project and have seen it done the same way on other examples throughout the web. Just be aware that RC1 Router has some bugs and issues which will be fixed in the final version.

Comment: Is it possible to use `[routerLink]` inside other components (like footer)?  In Angular1 I can use `href='#whatever-view'` everywhere, but in Angular2 if I use `href='my-link'`, the whole application will reload, use `[routerLink]` gave me `ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: No provider for Router!` error...